# AWS SQS Queue: AmazonClientException: Failed to schedule request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo, sqslistener

Getting this error when trying to upload the message in AWS SQS queue:

```
Error in calling sqs
Failed to send message to QueueMessageChannel[QueueMessageChannel@2bc20c83];
nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Failed to schedule request
{QueueUrl: https://sqs.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/091072499599/abc-ABC_REPOSITORY_SERVICE_QUEUE_DEV,
MessageBody:{"ABCRequestId":"YmNjZGI0ZDktZmM3NS00MzdkLTlhZTctMTg0NWUxN2Q4MjQ5"}
```

Comment: Can you tell us anything more? For example, does this happen _every_ time you try to send a message to the queue? Did it previously work okay? Can you show us the code that generated this error? It _seems_ to be a client-side error, so where is it being sent from (eg an EC2 instance in a private subnet)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Previously it was working okay, for some soap/xml request it working for some soap+xml payload getting this error, by giving SQS queue permission to write from EC2 instance, I am trying

Comment: Might be due to the size of the payload